# How to add transparent buttons on an already existing background in Python?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, transparent

I can't find answer for my question anywhere so i decided to ask here.

I star a Python project and i want to add some Buttons on my app's background.
I try Tkinter but this adds a "sub-window" in my app's window, not a button.

I want transparent buttons because in my background there are already graphical buttons. Each button will do a command.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say your background already has the look of a button, you don't need to add an additional button. Instead, you should determine the coordinates of the bounding rectangle for each 'pseudo-button' and then create event bindings that will perform actions if the user clicks within those bounds.

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        # (x1, y1) is the upper left point of the rectangle
        # (x2, y2) is the lower right point of the rectangle
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        return

    def contains(self, newx, newy):
        # Will return true if the point (newx, newy) lies within the rectangle.
        # False otherwise.
        return (self.x1 <= newx <= self.x2) and (self.y1 <= newy <= self.y2) 


try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTK, Image


def button_click(event):
    # The location of the click is stored in event sent by tkinter
    # and can be accessed like:
    print("You clicked ({}, {})".format(event.x, event.y))

    ## Now that you're in here, you can determine if the user clicked
    ## inside one of your buttons. If they did, perform the action that
    ## you want. For example, I've created two rectangle objects which
    ## simulate the location of some.

    button1_rect = Rectangle( 100, 100, 200, 200 )
    button2_rect = Rectangle( 300, 300, 400, 400 )
    # Change the rectangles to reflect your own button locations.

    if button1_rect.contains(event.x, event.y):
        print("You clicked button number 1!")

    if button2_rect.contains(event.x, event.y):
        print("You clicked button number 2!")


    return

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(master = root, height = 500, width = 500)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", button_click)
# The above command means whenever <Button-1> (left mouse button) is clicked
# within your canvas, the button_click function will be called. 

canvas.pack()
your_background = ImageTK.PhotoImage(Image.open("info_screen.png")) # <-- Or whatever image you want...
canvas.create_image(20, 20, image = your_background)
# 20, 20 represents the top left corner for where your image will be placed

root.mainloop()
```

Run that and click around while watching your console

Read more about binding to tkinter events here: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.html

Comment: Thank u for ur response. I tried your solution but when i run it, appears a blank tk window and only if i close it, appears my original background - window. The prints of clicks works only in the first window (tk), not on mine.

Here's my [code](https://github.com/vkarof/Kiosk/blob/master/test_1)

Comment: @VaggelisKarof The code I posted is an example of how to bind a mouse-click event to a tkinter object. Your code uses pygame which has a different event-binding subsystem from tkinter. I have never used pygame before but I found this (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the documentation. In your "while not done" loop, you should check the event to see if it is a "pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN" or "pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP" (depending on what kind of behavior you want). If it is, get the position with "pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()". Try going from there.

Comment: I use pygame because i didn't knew how to build my app, and i have used pygame on a project before. Can i write my whole app with tkinter, without pygame? My app concerns a kiosk project. Sorry but i'm new in programming:(

Comment: Again, I've never used pygame in my life so take my answer with a grain of salt -- If your app allows the user to interact by pressing buttons only then I would  use tkinter. If there are any animation aspects or things that could be considered gameplay, I would use pygame. I edited my previous answer to include loading an image into a tkinter canvas.